# Running models eagerly in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have noticed that even after compiling the model with `.compile(..., run_eagerly=False)`, the print statements in `.call()` keep working. Does that mean that `.call()` is to be manually wrapped in a `tf.function`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`run_eagerly` in `compile()` influence the attr `tf.keras.Model.run_eagerly`, but not used in `call()`. Because, `call()` is `NotImplemented` in tf.keras.Model, its used for custom training mode, not for "comple() fit()" coding mode. You can find the `tf.function` wrap logic in
[tf.keras.Model.make_train_function](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.9.0/keras/engine/training.py#L998-L1097), which used by `fit()` automatically to wrap `train_step()` etc., which are higher level logics than `call()`.